# How to make my C program compiled with SysV calling convention run under MinGW

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw, x86-64, calling-convention

My platform is **x86_64** + **Windows 10** + **Cygwin**. My compiler is `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`.

For some reason, I had to compile my program with `-mabi=sysv` option, and I would like to avoid the default `-mabi=ms` option if it is possible at all.

The program compiled successfully. But when it calls library functions like `printf`, it **segfaults**. The reason is that the library functions reside in `msvcrt.dll`, which was probably prebuilt with a calling convention other than `-mabi=sysv`.

So, is there a way to install libraries compiled with `-mabi=sysv` in **Cygwin**?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why do you need this?

Comment: @ssbssa The project I am working on has hand written x86 assembly in it. The hand-written assembly code uses ```sysv``` calling convention. Now we are porting it to a **mingw** environment, whose default is ```ms```, and we think it would be nice to just install ```sysv``` libraries without rewriting the assembly part. But since we didn't find a way to do that, we have already rewritten the assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to avoid this, e.g. by using macros in your asm to adapt it between calling conventions.  [Agner Fog's calling convention guide](https://www.agner.org/optimize/) has some suggestions, e.g. `#ifdef` or `%if` some extra `mov` instructions ahead of the function to put args in the registers the rest of the function was written for.  (And then don't use the red zone or shadow space, lowest common denominator, if your function can still work efficiently that way.)

IDK if the same `.cfi` directives could create correct stack-unwind metadata for both MS and SysV versions, but if you just use your SysV assembly you're unlikely to have SEH-safe code that fully complies with the Windows ABI.

---

#### Per-function attributes to specify calling convention

If you declare every hand-written asm function's prototype with `__attribute__((sysv_abi))`, GCC will make code that calls it correctly.

[The GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) also says:

> Note, the `ms_abi` attribute for Microsoft Windows 64-bit targets currently requires the `-maccumulate-outgoing-args` option.

Of course, any callback function-pointers you pass into the asm functions also need to be `__attribute__((ms_abi))`, so if you want to pass the address of any Windows library function, you'll need to write your own wrapper for it which uses that in the definition.

---

**This comes at some performance overhead**, because the SysV ABI allows clobbering all XMM regs, but MS-ABI doesn't, so every function that calls any SysV-ABI function needs to save/restore xmm6-15.  This also bloats those call-sites, which can be mitigated by having GCC use a helper function to save / restore those mismatched registers:

> `-mcall-ms2sysv-xlogues`
> Due to differences in 64-bit ABIs, any Microsoft ABI function that calls a System V ABI function must consider RSI, RDI and XMM6-15 as clobbered. By default, the code for saving and restoring these registers is emitted inline, resulting in fairly lengthy prologues and epilogues. Using -mcall-ms2sysv-xlogues emits prologues and epilogues that use stubs in the static portion of libgcc to perform these saves and restores, thus reducing function size at the cost of a few extra instructions.

---

#### Example (on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:54,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:54,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:54,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:54,startLineNumber:9),source:%27//%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+SYSV+__attribute__((sysv_abi))%0A%0ASYSV+int+foo(int+x,+double)%3B%0A%0Aint+bar(int+*p,+double+d)+%7B%0A++++*p+%3D+0%3B++++++++++++++++++++//+incoming+arg+in+RCX%0A++++int+tmp+%3D+foo(p%5B12%5D,+d)%3B%0A++++*p+%3D+tmp%3B%0A++++return+tmp%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.18650426798238,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3++-mabi%3Dms%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.791002845321586,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mabi%3Dms+-Wall+-maccumulate-outgoing-args%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:49.20899715467842,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

```
#define SYSV __attribute__((sysv_abi))

SYSV int foo(int x, double);

// no attribute so this function is the default MS-ABI
int bar(int *p, double d) {
    *p = 0;                    // incoming arg in RCX
    int tmp = foo(p[12], d);
    *p = tmp;
    return tmp;
}
```

Build with `-O3 -mabi=ms -Wall -maccumulate-outgoing-args` with Linux GCC11.2.  `-mabi=ms` is a rough simulation of building with Cygwin or MinGW.

```
bar:
        push    rdi
        movapd  xmm0, xmm1                  # SysV wants first FP arg in XMM0
        push    rsi                         # save RDI/RSI, call-preserved in MS-ABI
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rcx
        sub     rsp, 160                     # shadow space + xmm spill space
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], 0          # deref pointer arg
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rcx+48]     # load a new 1st arg
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm6     # save the MS-abi call-preserved regs
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+16], xmm7
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+32], xmm8
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+48], xmm9
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+64], xmm10
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+80], xmm11
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+96], xmm12
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+112], xmm13
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+128], xmm14
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+144], xmm15
        call    foo
        movaps  xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
        movaps  xmm7, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        movaps  xmm8, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        movaps  xmm9, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax
        movaps  xmm10, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+64]
        movaps  xmm11, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+80]
        movaps  xmm12, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+96]
        movaps  xmm13, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+112]
        movaps  xmm14, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+128]
        movaps  xmm15, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+144]
        add     rsp, 160
        pop     rbx
        pop     rsi
        pop     rdi
        ret
```

Note that all this XMM save/restore would still happen even if there were no `double` or `float` args; the caller has to assume the callee might be using SIMD or FP internally.  Fortunately only the low xmm part of high vector regs are call-preserved, even with AVX enabled, so the stack space usage doesn't get worse.

If I'd used a `__m128d` arg, [x64 fastcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170) (the default with `ms_abi`) would pass it by reference, pointed to by RDX.  `vectorcall` would have passed it in XMM1 like a `double` (not xmm0 because arg-register numbering isn't independent between int and FP in MS-ABI). I don't know how to use x64 vectorcall with GCC.  `__attribute__((vectorcall))` is ignored if used on `bar`.

vs. with both parts compiled as MS-ABI (commenting out the SYSV on the prototype):

```
bar:
        push    rbx                        # save a call-preserved reg (and realign the stack)
        mov     rbx, rcx                     # save incoming arg around function call
        sub     rsp, 32                    # reserve shadow space
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], 0           # deref the arg
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rcx+48]    # load a new 1st arg
                                           # 2nd arg still in XMM1
        call    foo
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax       # save return value
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbx
        ret                                # and return with it in EAX
```

###### Clang ignores `-mabi=ms`, but respects `__attribute__((ms_abi))`

So a Windows build of clang that defaults to MS-ABI can probably use `__attribute__((sysv))`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment about handwritten assembly, it seems you're experiencing firsthand how not so portable assembly actually is and why historically there was a need for a more portable higher level language like C.

The reason why you have a crash is likely due to the difference in register usage between the two ABIs. When calling a function, an ABI defines what registers are associated with each of the arguments. So when you call a library function using one ABI where the library was previously compiled for a different ABI, that library code will look at its specified registers and potentially access memory leading to undefined behavior.

I think that there is a misunderstanding though that obtaining libraries will solve your problem. Think for a moment that you get what you want, the windows C runtime library compiled against the System V ABI. Now when your program calls `printf(...)` you will at least have your arguments in the right registers. But the text has to be printed to the console, so the kernel has to be asked to step in and make it happen. In order to make that system call, the windows API library will be used and yet another ABI mismatch will occur. So you can see how this dilemma goes up to the top. You would basically need a complete windows OS compiled against the System V ABI, or some other form of compatibility layer like how WINE works.

You may have two options here. Rewrite the assembly to match the native windows ABI, or look into using WSL which provides a full (but virtualized) Linux environment.